# Grails cobertura plugin is doing code coverage on BuildConfig.groovy

Tags: grails, code-coverage, cobertura

Grails coberatura plugin is doing code coverage on BuildConfig.groovy. I have tried all these configurations on BuildConfiguration to exclude BuildConfiguration from code coverage have tried all these.

```
coverage {
    exclusions = [
        '*/BuildConfig*',
        'BuildConfig*',
        "BuildConfig*",
        'BuildConfig',
        'BuildConfig*'
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this to exclude most of the unneeded files

```
coverageExcludes = [
        "**/*BootStrap*",
        "Config*",
        "**/conf/**",
        "**/*DataSource*",
        "**/*resources*",
        "**/*UrlMappings*",
        "**/*Tests*",
        "**/grails/test/**",
        "**/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/**",
        "**/PreInit*",
        "*GrailsPlugin*"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`'**/BuildConfig*'` works.

The excludes list uses the same pattern matching rules as [ant](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).  To match any path prefix, use the double star; a single star only matches one directory deep.

Answer (score 0):

The code-coverage plugin excludes `BuildConfig.groovy` by default. Here is the default list of excluded files (from the [`_Events.groovy`](http://svn.codehaus.org/grails-plugins/grails-code-coverage/trunk/scripts/_Events.groovy) script in the plugin):

```
codeCoverageExclusionList = [
        "**/*BootStrap*",
        "Config*",
        "BuildConfig*",
        "**/*DataSource*",
        "**/*resources*",
        "**/*UrlMappings*",
        "**/*Tests*",
        "**/grails/test/**",
        "**/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/**",
        "**/PreInit*",
        "*GrailsPlugin*"]
```

*(Not sure what version this was added, but it's there as of 1.2.4)*